# onResponse variable is null in void run()

Tags: android, android-studio, androidhttpclient

I'd like to get color value inside void run, how can I do this? any example?
color is null there.

```
   public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
        String color = response.body().string();
        Profile.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setTheme(color); //color is null here.
            }
        }
    }
```

color is null inside run()
full code:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.context = getApplicationContext();
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
            .url("http://ip/color.php")
            .build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
            String color = response.body().string();
            Profile.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setTheme(color);
                }
            }
        }
    });...
```

Comment: It should be `final`. I wonder how are you able to even compile.

Comment: Please post the response you are getting.

Comment: @AsutoshPanda I'm not compiling. it says: variable color is access from within inner class

Answer (score 1):

If it says variable **color** is accessed from within inner class,
make the variable **color** as Global.
Declare it outside your onCreate.

Or make it final

```
final String color = response.body().string();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code shouldn't compile as you cannot access non final variable inside of "closure". 
So the only change you need is

```
final String color = response.body().string();
Profile.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
          setTheme(color);
     }
}
```